# Adding Xamarin app a searchbar

Tags: sqlite, search, xamarin

I made a simple Xamarin Cross platform SQLite app which can inserts, updates, deletes data from a listview. I want to add a searchbar. Following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4b4ZlSsaDi8) tutorial i added this on my HomePage.xaml

1. 

Now if my listview's source was a list just like in the tutorial i had to write this in HomePage.xaml.cs

```
 private void mySearchBar_ButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string searchText = mySearchBar.Text;
            myListView.ItemsSource=ListViewsListSource.Where(name=>name.Contains(searchText ));
        }
```

But i defined my listview's source like this.

```
using (var dataaccess= new DataAccess())
            {

                listaListView.ItemsSource = dataaccess.GetEmployers();
            }
```

And *GetEmployers* is defined in DataAccess

```
public List<Employer> GetEmployers()
        {
            return connection.Table<Employer>().OrderBy(c => c.Lastname).ToList();
        }
```

Now what should i write in *mySearchBar_ButtonPressed* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to approach this.  Following your own example, you could add a Search method to your DataAccess class

```
public List<Employer> SearchEmployers(string key)
        {
            return connection.Table<Employer>().Where(e => e.Lastname.Contains(key) || e.FirstName.Contains(key)).OrderBy(c => c.Lastname).ToList();
        }

private void mySearchBar_ButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string searchText = mySearchBar.Text;
            listaListView.ItemsSource = dataaccess.SearchEmployers(searchText);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. How can i make search with multiple variable.(Searchbar is going to search for firstname or lastname.)


************************

return connection.Table<Employer>().Where(e => e.Lastname.Contains(key)).OrderBy(c => c.Lastname).ToList();
        }

*******************


I can't figure out where to add OR in this.